# asp caching CSS file

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, web

Hi i am coding a classic ASP and when i import my CSS its getting cached i want to be able to either be able to remove it from the cache. because i am only using the CSS file in a specific scenario.

can anyone help please.

```
<% If Session("SG_bIsRemoteBetslip")= True then %>
<style type="text/css" media="screen, tv, projection">
@import url(/Marketing/Site-Files/Sportsbook/Betslip/remote-betslip.css);
</style>
<% Session("SG_bIsRemoteBetslip") = False %>
<% End If %>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with caching the css?  Or do instead mean that the `IF` statement isn't doing what you expected?  Also why are you using @import instead of using the `src` attribute of the style tag?

Answer (score 2):

You could prevent the css from caching by simply passing a querystring to the src:

```
<% 
If Session("SG_bIsRemoteBetslip")= True then
    response.write "<style type=""text/css"" media=""screen, tv, projection"" href=""/Marketing/Site-Files/Sportsbook/Betslip/remote-betslip.css?ID=" & Server.urlencode(now()) & """ />"
    Session("SG_bIsRemoteBetslip") = False   
End If
%>
```

It's certainly not glamorous but it can be a quick and easy way to force a recent css change to all your visitors regardless of their cache.